# Using Java to run a Python application and then parse its output

Tags: java, python

So I'm currently working on a project which is using Java for it's GUI and a python script to perform the primary functions of the program.

I was wondering if there is a way to run the python script from within the application directory, and then send its output to the GUI program for parsing. The output could be JSON/YAML/Plaintext etc (so this will be parsed by the GUI).

**Two options** I thought of (which may or may not work) were:

1. Running the Python program separately and having it output a file which is then read by the Java program (This is my least favourite)
2. Using `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.exec` to run the Python program.. But then how would I get the output?

If neither of my options I thought of are feasible or would work, then is there a way to do this much better?

Thanks!

Comment: Both would work, but I'd prefer `ProcessBuilder#redirectOutput(Redirect)` and `redirectError`. Use separate threads for reading from the stream, otherwise the process may hang after filling its output buffers.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime.exec gives you an input stream that can be wrapped in a buffered reader to parse the output.

```
      try {

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python 1.py'");

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        // read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        // read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Comment: Your example is quite unclear. To me it just looks like your reading in a file called `write.txt`, so it doesn't really answer my question as to whether I can effectively execute the python script to get its output